# how to install requestracker 3.8 on debian-lenny with aptitude?

Tags: request-tracker

i want to install Request tracker on my debian server, i want to do it through aptitude, is this posible ? i try to add de backports to the source list following this tutorial: http://requesttracker.wikia.com/wiki/DebianInstallGuide , however i get the

```
Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "request-tracker3.8"
```

When i try:

```
aptitude install request-tracker3.8
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Did you run `apt-get update` or `aptitude update` after you added the backports to your sources.list ?

request-tracker is available on my system where backports are enabled:

```
petrus@tank:~$ aptitude search request-tracker
p   request-tracker3.6        - Extensible trouble-ticket tracking system
p   request-tracker3.8        - extensible trouble-ticket tracking system
```